# PowerShell - Inserting newline char in string during regex replace

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to search a string for some numbers and insert a new line before each, not including the first one.

I don't seem to be able to use the traditional regex \n char to insert a newline. If I use the PowerShell escape character, the regex variable from the set is ignored.

For a given source string of

```
$theString = "1. First line 2. Second line 3. Third line"
```

What I want is:

```
1. First Line
2. Second Line
3. Third line
```

So I tried this regex to find the numbers 2 to 9 followed by a period and a space:

```
$theString = $theString -replace '([2-9]\. )','\n$1'
```

but that yields:

```
1. First line\n2. Second line\n3. Third line
```

So I tried using the PowerShell escape character for a newline and put it inside double inverted commas:

```
$theString = $theString -replace '([2-9]\. )',"`n$1"
```

but that yields:

```
1. First Line
Second Line
Third line
```

I tried using `\r`, `\r\n`, `` \`r ``, `` \`r\`n ``, etc. trying to force the linebreak, but can't get it to happen without losing the ability to include the current regex variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is caused as `$` is used both for ordinary Powershell variables and capture groups. In order to process it as a capture group identifier, single quotes `'` are needed. But single quote tells Powershell not to interpret the newline escape as a newline but literal `` `n ``.

Catenating two differently quoted strings does the trick. Like so,

```
$theString -replace '([2-9]\. )', $("`n"+'$1')
1. First line
2. Second line
3. Third line
```

As an alternative, use double quotes `"` and escape the dollar. Like so,

```
$theString -replace '([2-9]\. )', "`n`$1"
1. First line
2. Second line
3. Third line
```

Yet another an alternative <sub>(thanks to Lieven)</sub> uses here-strings. A here-string contains a newline. Maybe a variable makes it easier to use. Like so,

```
$repl = @'

$1
'@

$theString -replace '([2-9]\. )', $repl
1. First line
2. Second line
3. Third line
```

Comment: I prefer the escape solution. Another solution would be a `here` string like  `"1. First line 2. Second line 3. Third line" -replace '([2-9]\. )', @'

$1
'@` *(note there's a crlf before $1!)*

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. The first method worked well for me. It's strange that the -Replace command will find a newline char within single quotes as the thing to search for.

Answer (score 1):

To allow any number I'd replace the leading space with a newline and use a [positive look ahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to filter on.

```
$theString = "1. First line 2. Second line 3. Third line 11. Eleventh line"
$thestring  -replace ' (?=[1-9]+\. )', "`n"
```

Sample output:

```
1. First line
2. Second line
3. Third line
11. Eleventh line
```

To have an array of strings output, with the same RegEx:

```
$thestring -split ' (?=[1-9]+\. )'
```

Comment: Makes sense. I ended up achieving the same by doing the replace twice, like this: $theString = $theString -replace '([1-9][0-9]\. )', $("\`n"+'$1')  ...and then $theString = $theString -replace '([2-9]\. )', $("\`n"+'$1')

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be:

```
$theString = "1. First line 2. Second line 3. Third line"
$theString -replace '(\s)([0-9]+\.)',([System.Environment]::NewLine+'$2')
```

which is actually pretty similar to your second line of code.